# Passing a HANDLE to a DLL

Tags: c, winapi, dllimport, dllexport, createfile

I'm new to Win32 programming.
I'm trying to pass a HANDLE obtained using CreateFile() to a function in a DLL.
But upon trying to read bytes, dwBytesRead says 0.
Am I allowed to pass HANDLEs to DLL entries? I read here [[Writing DLLs]](http://web.archive.org/web/20120118072249/http://www.openwatcom.org/index.php/Writing_DLLs) that resources of the caller do not belong to callee, and hence I should not call CloseHandle() or things like free() for malloc() in caller.
Is my understanding correct? Kindly point me in the right direction. Here's the code:
**main.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 5

int __declspec( dllimport ) hello( HANDLE );

void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hFile; 

    printf("\n");
    if( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("Usage Error: Incorrect number of arguments\n\n");
        _tprintf(TEXT("Usage:\n\t%s <text_file_name>\n"), argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    hFile = CreateFile(argv[1],               // file to open
                       GENERIC_READ,          // open for reading
                       FILE_SHARE_READ,       // share for reading
                       NULL,                  // default security
                       OPEN_EXISTING,         // existing file only
                       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, // normal file
                       NULL);                 // no attr. template

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        _tprintf(TEXT("Terminal failure: unable to open file \"%s\" for read.\n"), argv[1]);
        return; 
    }

    printf( "Entered main, calling DLL.\n" );
    hello(hFile);
    printf( "Back in main, exiting.\n" );
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

**hello.c**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 5
DWORD g_BytesTransferred = 0;

VOID CALLBACK FileIOCompletionRoutine(
  __in  DWORD dwErrorCode,
  __in  DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered,
  __in  LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped )
 {
  _tprintf(TEXT("Error code:\t%x\n"), dwErrorCode);
  _tprintf(TEXT("Number of bytes:\t%x\n"), dwNumberOfBytesTransfered);
  g_BytesTransferred = dwNumberOfBytesTransfered;
 }

int __declspec( dllexport ) hello( HANDLE hFile )
{
    DWORD  dwBytesRead = 0;
    char   ReadBuffer[BUFFERSIZE] = {0};
    OVERLAPPED ol = {0};

    if( FALSE == ReadFileEx(hFile, ReadBuffer, BUFFERSIZE-1, &ol, FileIOCompletionRoutine) )
    {
        DWORD lastError = GetLastError();
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to read from file.\n GetLastError=%08x\n", lastError);
        return lastError;
    }
    dwBytesRead = g_BytesTransferred;

    if (dwBytesRead > 0 && dwBytesRead <= BUFFERSIZE-1)
    {
        ReadBuffer[dwBytesRead]='\0';

        printf("Data read from file (%d bytes): \n", dwBytesRead);
        printf("%s\n", ReadBuffer);
    }
    else if (dwBytesRead == 0)
    {
        printf("No data read from file \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n ** Unexpected value for dwBytesRead ** \n");
    }

    printf( "Hello from a DLL!\n" );

    return( 0 );
}
```

Comment: The same article says: 'If you (on Win32) CreateFile in a DLL, you can CloseFile the same file in the main executable or in another DLL.' How is this achieved?

Comment: Does your program work as expected if the `hello`function is part of main.c instead of being in a dll?

Comment: Yes, it's actually copied from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx
I compiled it on Visual C++ 10.

Comment: There is no problem with passing handles between DLLs, they are global to the process.

Comment: You need to get the code working *without* using a DLL first.  Then when you do put it in a DLL you'll find it makes no difference.

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` looks like the root cause of your problems to me

Comment: Yes, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED could be another way to look at a resolution, specifying different I/O access mode thereby eliminating the  Sleep() call. However, if desired, it cannot be avoided.

Comment: Why do you want to sleep?

Comment: Using asynchronous I/O will prompt for wait, as callback will need some context-switch, hence the wait for FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED. If a different blocking access is specified, something like FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, the Sleep() call might be avoided. If asynchronous access is the demand of the situation, then FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED cannot be avoided.

Comment: You should note that the sample code you started with isn't really correct either.  It calls SleepEx and then simply assumes that since you've exited the I/O must have completed.  In real-world code you would want to have a loop that actually checks whether the I/O is done or not, since the sleep might have exited for some other reason.  (Although in most cases the code would look completely different anyway, because usually if you are using overlapped I/O it is because you want to do something else while waiting for the I/O to complete.)

Comment: Oh, and FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH is independent of whether you're using synchronous or asynchronous I/O.

Comment: I suppose I'll need more insight before using 'CreateFile' family functions, or Win32 in general. It's a little complex API for starters. Thanks for help though. Maybe I'll start with a few books on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `SleepEx(5000, TRUE)` call from the example.

You are using async-io, in which case you will receive a callback when the read occurs. If you don't wait for the callback you *may* get `0` bytes read depending on when the callback is triggered.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the case. I missed about the asynchronous I/O.
But it still can read only 4 bytes.
Is the Open Watcom documentation relevant in this case?
What are the things to be careful about while writing DLLs for Windows NT?

Comment: You're only reading 4 bytes because your code only *asks* to read 4 bytes.  Using a DLL has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Yes, as @HarryJohnston says, you try to read only `BUFFERSIZE - 1` bytes.

Comment: Yeah, how could I have missed that! This is the difference between code written, and code copied.:) Anyways, thanks for the answers.
Is the aforementioned document relevant for NT?

Comment: @user2338150, when you are doing anything about Windows NT, try to read through all of the relevant documentation in MSDN. The `CreateFile` and `ReadFileEx` are very intricate operations with a lot of functionality that are not similar to calls in other operating systems.

Comment: Ok, got it...rtfm...:) Thanks, again for the answers. Cheers!

Comment: I'll still wait for one more answer though, to mark it accepted. Besides, the reason this question was ever posted was to get more than working code. The actual problem I faced was a variation on this, and like user1952500 said, 'CreateFile' and 'ReadFileEx' being very intricate it's difficult to understand their use without proper technical reference.

Comment: Yes, sure. I think if @HarryJohnston makes his comments about using a DLL a little more generic, that would be a better answer for this context than mine.

Comment: And @user2338150, I didn't mean the `f` in `rtfm` when I asked you to read the MSDN documentation. The documentation is extensive and each line could lead to varied results (especially while developing kernel-mode drivers). It is good to read the whole description of the API _including_ the comments at the end since some users mention possible bugs and extensions to the document that way.

Comment: @user1952500, I didn't mean any offence. I just said so out of silly humor. The documentation on MSDN is vast and I admit at having superficially skimmed through some of it. I understand, that I need to read it with sufficient depth. Can you suggest some good books on the topic?

Comment: @user2338150,no offence taken. I don't know of anything better than the MSDN documentation unfortunately. It is long and tough but you won't need to know all the details until you use the 'special' commands.